# Java generics extends in type parameter

Tags: java, generics

i have problem in my java project recently with generics. the following is the simplified version of my actual problem.

```
abstract class Value{
    public int value;

    Value(int v){ value = v; }
}

class Wrap<T> {
    T data;

    Wrap(T data){ this.data = data; }    

    public void add(T value){
        data = actualAdd(data, value);
    }

    public T actualAdd(T p1, T p2){/* other code. don't worry */}
}
```

easy to see, i want to inherit `Value` afterwards.

but when it comes to combine both, i.e.:

```
Wrap<? extends Value> wrapValue;
```

i really wish `add` recieves `Value`, i.e.:

```
wrapValue.add(Value value)
```

instead of

```
wrapValue.add(? extends Value value)
```

since i just want to add up the value, the other fields are irrelevant.

i know how to do it in static method, that should be:

```
public static void staticAdd(Wrap<? extends T> wrapper, T value){/**/}
```

but how can i have the same trick in method member?

Comment: Don't use `Wrap<? extends Value>`, you won't be allowed to set anything.

Comment: use Wrap<Value> instead

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i don't need to set anything internally. i just want the `add` method functioning.

Comment: The `add` method is setting something. Thus, you cannot use it. I recommend you to read here: [What is PECS?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/1065197)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza so i can't do the similar thing like `staticAdd` to `Wrap` itself?

Comment: You can do it but for consumers, which is not really your case. In fact, that method definition doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i've thought a while but it seems i am still confused a little bit. could you show me how to make `Wrap<? extends Value>` have method with signature of `Value`? i am curious.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza oh, now i understand what you were talking about. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`PECS (Producer Extends and Consumer Super)` is the way to go here. Try using `? super Value`.

[Here](http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/07/24/java-generics-what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super/) is one post, which might help you with more context on this.